# apache rewrite htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying things on my server but I can't figure out what's going wrong.
As of now, this is the .htaccess I have:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [NC, L]
```

Instead of rewriting to 'match' it rewrites to 'match'.php
Any idea why?

Comment: This is not a programming question.  I suggest asking at http://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 0):

The [*MultiViews* option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) can cause such a behavior. Try to disable it.